# Synonymize [char] and [character]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Not your typical [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request), as I'm genuinely conflicted about this one.

- [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) has 3,723 questions
- [char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) has 6,156 questions

They seem like they're the same, but maybe they're not - one is often a primitive data type, but when you start thinking about unicode / wide characters they're often not a `char` anymore...

@JonClements in chat:

> I bet the blocker is that char for the C/C++/similar languages brigade is just generally going to be a plain old datatype (possibly signed 8bits) while character is generic for a char/unicode/wide etc... abstraction?

I'm actively looking for discussion on the topic. What do you think, meta?

Comment: [char] is fine as a datatype, [character] isn't helpful

Comment: I'm sure there are posts who's main issue has to do with character/s, but I'm not sure if the tag itself is useful in categorizing the posts. And I'm pretty sure there are no experts in the field of [tag:character]

Comment: I am of the opinion that [tag:character] is a meta tag and should be burninated,

Comment: @NathanOliver Could you elaborate further in an answer?

Comment: [A reference for others as to what qualifies as "meta tag"](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  Offhand, I wouldn't qualify "character" as one.

Comment: [character] is not in anyway a meta tag.  But I agree with Deduplicator that it is too broad.

Answer (score 19):

I appreciate and somewhat share the conflict here, but I would ultimately cite that [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) ***(relating to those elements of written language, known more formally as user-perceived characters or graphemes)*** and [char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) ***(relating to a datatype)*** describe distinct things, with only some overlap in the domain of programming.

There are questions about `char`s that don't deal with characters, and questions about characters that don't deal with `char`.

Neither one eclipses the other, so regardless of the suitability of [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character), they certainly should **not** be synonymized.

Comment: Please give your definition of "character" too. Because there are *so many*...

Comment: @Deduplicator Your breakdown of the interpretations of "character" is very insightful.  I believe that - other than "A byte." - everything else you list could be pooled into an *area of expertise* having to do with the concept of a  [tag:character].

Comment: Well, those are related concepts, so there is an "area of expertise", if you want to see it that way, in being able to **differentiate between** them. Like there's one for C and C++...

Comment: perhaps it would help if we changed `character ` to `text-character` or something else more semantic.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: Which definition is or is not a text-character?

Comment: `char` is a datatype in C-like languages. `text-character` is a character one would use in output text.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: You are repeating yourself. What the heck is a text-character? Is it a codeunit, codepoint, grapheme, or something else entirely?

Comment: @Deduplicator I suppose if I had to define it like that, I'd say it's the value (e.g. `A`) at a code point of a given character encoding (e.g. `U+0041`, `ASCII 41`, etc.).

Comment: @Deduplicator Essentially what I'd separate is the actual glyph, as has been used in printing and typography for centuries, from the C-like datatype that we have used to represent it for decades.

Comment: @Ben: Your first comment (14h ago) means it's a codepoint, however many codeunits that might mean. Your second (30min ago) confuses the issue, at the same time insisting it's a codeunit and grapheme. Please take the time to understand what those terms mean before trying to say which you mean. That way, there's a chance what you say and what you mean might be unambiguous and actually what you *wanted* to say...

Comment: Hopefully these two images and their descriptions illustrate my mindset without me having to re-evaluate the wording of my proposition: http://imgur.com/a/9qFZi My proposition hinges on the concept that there are more ways to internalize a character in memory than the C-like `char` datatype, and that the actual concept of the character is completely separate from how it's represented in memory.

Answer (score 8):

I think [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) should be killed for being hopelessly ambiguous.
It *could* mean:

- A byte. Especially when using an SBCS (most likely ASCII, sometimes EBCDIC derived, rarely more obscure). Or when using C or a derived language.
- A codeunit (which might coincidentally be a byte, see UTF-8).
- A codepoint (which might coincidentally be a codeunit, see UTF-32).
  Or for some subset of values coincide with a codeunit, see especially UTF-16, where that confusion is rampant.
- A grapheme (also known as user-perceived character). Represented by one to many codepoints.
- An abstract character which isn't actually yet representable as a grapheme. Though those are getting really rare.

The most harmful aspect though is that most using the term, be they asker, answerer or commenter, are completely oblivious, stumbling around in the dark and bumping into things and each other.

Comment: While it's better to stick to unambiguous terminology, the fact that people refer to different concepts with one term may suggest that they don't know or are not aware of the precise terminology. While killing the tag may result in people not tagging their question with [tag:character], it may also result in people misusing [tag:char] for the same purpose.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Somehow, I fail to see how your points aren't covered in my answer. And at least if they tag it `char`, we have a specific definition we can depend on to determine whether it's mis-tagged and correcting that.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is a better solution. That's all. With or without the tags, we still end up with tags that are prone to misuse.

Comment: @Deduplicator perhaps a new question "Is [tag:character] hopelessly ambiguous?" is appropriate.  I think you make good points here that might deviate too much from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion that [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) is a meta tag and should be burninated.  Mainly I cite the help section:

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question....

On SO I don't think that [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) could be the only tag that is used on a question.

Comment: Can [tag:char] work as the only tag on a question?

Comment: @durron597 Okay [tag:char] probably couldn't be the only tag on the question but if I tag a question [tag:c++] and [tag:char] it is pretty clear that is a question regarding a `char` in C++ where if I did [tag:c++] and [tag:character] it to me is lacking something to describe [tag:character].

Comment: I've been peeking at the [recent `character` questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character) and I'm starting to conclude that **it is being used as a meta-tag**.  While it *could* be used as an area of expertise, in practice it seems to just signify that the word is present in the title.